# How to perform addition in a Linq query

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

My query is like

```
var query = dbContext.table1.join(dbcontext.table2,i=>i.table1.id,j=>j.table2.id,
                 (i,j)=>new {
                     name = i.name,
                     hours = (new decimal?[]{ j.day1,j.day2,j.day3}.Sum()),
                     total = ???????
                 }).ToArray();
```

In the hours field I am getting the values of individual user's working hours for three days.  In the "total" field I want to display the sum of all users' "hours" values.

Can you tell me how to get the "total" value?

Comment: I assume, that the total will be the same in all items of your array? Then, why have it in the item at all? I suggest you have that as additional value outside the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var total = query.Sum(x => x.hours);
```

Since this total is for all rows in the result set, you do not want one value for each row, but one value representing the aggregate of the entire array.